# Just curious about result from NumPy function!

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have used NumPy for my Master thesis. I've converted parts of the code from MATLAB code, but I have doubts in NumPy/Python when I reference:

```
m = numpy.ones((10,2))
m[:,0]
```

which returns:

```
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

and when I ref to:

```
m[:,0:1]
```

it returns:

```
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
```

that I think it should be, cause same result with MATLAB!!!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you'd proofread your question and format it properly.

Comment: this should help a bit, though I still don't understand the question exactly!

Comment: thank you very much, for formatting, Amro :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget what numpy does, but Matlab indexes vectors from 1, not 0.  So array(:,0) is an error in Matlab.

Answer (score 5):

This is because numpy has the concept of 1d arrays which Matlab doesn't have. Coupled with numpys [broadcasting](https://web.archive.org/web/20130510041858/http://www.scipy.org:80/EricsBroadcastingDoc) this provides a powerful simplification (less worrying about inserting transposes everywhere) but does mean you have to think a little bit about translating from Matlab. In this case, extracting a single column with a scalar Numpy simplifies the result to a 1d array - but with a slice it preserves the original dimensions. If you want to stay closer to Matlab semantics you could try using the Matrix class. See [NumPy for matlab users](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) page for details. In this case, you could do either of the following:

```
m[:,0][:,newaxis] # gives same as matlab
np.matrix(m)[:,0] # gives same as matlab
```

But remember if you use matrix class `*` becomes matrix multiplication and you need to use `multiply()` for elementwise. (This is all covered in NumPy for Matlab Users page). Generally I would recommend trying to get used to using 1d arrays where you would have column or row vector in matlab and generally things just work. You only need to worry about column vs row when reassembling them into a 2d array.

You may be interested in automated matlab to python converters such as [OMPC](http://ompc.juricap.com/) [(paper)](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/neuro.11.005.2009/full) (I think there are others as well).

Comment: no problem... If you feel this answers the question you could click on the tick by the answer to accept it... :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm still learning Python myself, but I think the way that *slicing* works is that indices point to in-between locations, therefore `0:1` only gets you the first column. Is this what you were asking about?

This is what the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) has to say:

> One way to remember how slices work is
>   to think of the indices as pointing
>   between characters, with the left edge
>   of the first character numbered 0.
>   Then the right edge of the last
>   character of a string of n characters
>   has index n, for example:

```
 +---+---+---+---+---+
 | H | e | l | p | A |
 +---+---+---+---+---+
 0   1   2   3   4   5
-5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

Comment: No m[:,0:1] is the equivalent of the matlab statement as shown in the question - this extracts column 0, equivalent to column 1 in Matlab. 0:2 is a slice covering, 0,1 which is both columns (so the whole array in this case)

Comment: I think this what the OP was trying to do, since (aside from the starting index) in MATLAB: `m(:,1:2)` gets you two columns, while in Python/NumPy: `m[:,0:1]` returns one column. I guess this is something to be clarified..

Comment: Agree its not clear - I read the question as asking about extracting a column - in matlab m(:,1) gives a 2d column vector - the same as m[:,0:1] in numpy, but m[:,0] in numpy gives a 1d array - I think the question was why this is different to matlab, but the slices translate as you say...

Comment: Yea, it's not definitely clear in the question. I meant the same as Amro: MATLAB m(:,1:2), NumPy m[:,0:2]